# If a Thrust device_vector's .begin() iterator is stored, does it still point to the correct position after a resize()?

Tags: c, cuda, iterator, thrust

For instance:

```
thrust::device_vector<float> vec(...);
thrust::device_vector<float>::iterator i = vec.begin();
vec.resize(...);    // vec may get reallocated and moved in memory here
```

Now, has `vec.begin()` also updated and still point validly to the start of `vec`?

Comment: @EdS. Well, theoretically that doesn't say anything about `thrust::device_vector`, but practically it will probably indeed behave exactly like a `std::vector` in this regard.

Comment: After a shrink yes; after a grow, no.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: That almost certainly isn't correct. The CUDA runtime library lacks a `realloc` function, so without checking the code, I would be incredibly surprised if `resize` isn't a `malloc`+ `memcpy`+ `free` sequence in thrust. In that case iterators will be invalidated.

Comment: @talonmies: Except that the STL documentation **requires** what I stated to be true.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Who is talking about the STL? This question is specifically asking about thrust, which is an *NVIDIA CUDA* template library. Some of its functionality is modelled after the STL, but it otherwise is completely different.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens The **C++ standard** (which I assume you meant with *"STL documentation"*, otherwise it would be even more out of place) can require what it wants, that doesn't create a conformance error in any third-party library completely unrelated to the C++ standard library and its rules.

Comment: @talonmies I would still wonder if *Thrust* does a reallocation even if the new size is smaller than the old one (neither do I know, though). You don't neccessarily need a `realloc` (`std::vector` doesn't have that either), you can just leave the memory as is and adjust the vector's size indicator appropriately.

Comment: @talonmies Just looked into the source and you'll indeed be surprised ;)

Comment: @ChristianRau: Are you going to share? I spend 30 minutes last night looking through the Thrust source code files, but couldn't find that for the vector resize method. (I'm a C & C# programmer mostly, so the template structure is new to me.)

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Well, if one finally managed to crawl through all the indirections, it indeed behaves like `std::vector`, reallocating on growth and just decreasing the size counter on shrinkage, contrary to what *talonmies* wrote and in line with what you wrote (but without the wrong implication that the C++ standard alone is any proof of the behaviour of *Thrust*, of course).

Comment: @ChristianRau: Merci beaucoup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon resizing, if the vector originally did not have enough space, your iterator will be invalidated, so you'd have to recall `vec.begin()` to get a new, valid iterator.